# is it possible to store data json to html (not table)

Tags: jquery, json

is it possible to show data html from json ?
i have example, but it just for table.

```
<table id="tables"
data-url="comments.php"  
data-row-style="rowStyle" 
data-toggle="table" 
data-show-refresh="true" 
data-show-toggle="true" 
data-show-columns="true" 
data-search="true" 
data-select-item-name="toolbar1" 
data-pagination="true" 
data-sort-name="name" 
data-sort-order="desc">
<thead>
<tr>
<th data-field="name" data-sortable="true" data-align="left">Name</th>
<th data-field="comments" data-sortable="true" data-align="left">comments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

i want to show/load data from json to html :

```
<h3>name</h3>//data from json
<p>comments</p>//data from json
```

comments.php

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/json');
include 'connection.php';

$select = mysql_query("select * from comments");
$row=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
    $arrayx=array(  "comments"=>$row['comments'],
                    "name"=>$row['name']);

    $rows[] = $arrayx;

}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

i have example json like that..

Comment: Yeah it is, use AJAX.

Comment: *"i have example, but it just for table"* - Your example is only HTML, it has no connection to JSON at all. What is the corresponding JS that you would use to populate that table from JSON?

Comment: i have add jsonComments.php

Answer (score 0):

It can't be inline in your HTML as you ask.

But using jQuery [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), it can be done this way:

HTML:

```
<h3 id="jsonName"></h3><!--data from json will be here -->
<p id="jsonComments"></p><!--data from json will be here -->
```

jQuery script:

```
$.get("comments.php","",function(data){
  $("#jsonName").html(data.name);
  $("#jsonComments").html(data.comments);

  //To look at the received json
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
},"json");
```

If your json has many objects... Use classes instead of ids.
And loop through the data.

Comment: I assumed that `comments.php` is returning a valid json.

Comment: I edited... Try it and post what you see in the console.